# Change <li> class of the current link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have following code to change the class of `li` if the browser url is the same string as the a href tag within that `li`.

The problem with my code is that it changes the class for all `li` elements, not just the ones containing the specific url.

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#subnav a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == document.URL) {
      $('li').addClass("selected");
    }
  });
});
```

**html**:

```
<div id="subnav">
  <ul class="tabrow">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->config->base_url()?>rankings/all"> Players</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->config->base_url()?>rankings/top-guilds"> Guilds</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->config->base_url()?>rankings/top-masterlevel">Master Level</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->config->base_url()?>rankings/top-voters">Voters</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->config->base_url()?>rankings/top-online">Online</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**solution if anyone needed.** Thanks to **nem035**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#subnav a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == document.URL) {
      $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that you are using the selector `$('li')`, which selects **all `<li>` elements**, not just the parent of the current `<a>` whose url you are comparing.

This is probably what you should do:

```
if($(this).attr('href') == document.URL){
  $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert u php:

```
<?php
$url = $this->config->base_url.'rankings/all';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== $url) echo(' class="selected" ');
?>
```